# Can't print proper peer message (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, p2p

I know that I am doing something wrong. The problem appear somewhere in the code bellow. Here is my repository code: https://github.com/justcain/chatP2P . Still fairly new to programming and do not have enough experience to figure this out on my own. Did the p2p chat app by following a tutorial (hard to find proper tutorials that help you do it from scratch). The image shows what output I get when a peer sends a message to another peer.[Image for the output I am getting][1]

````
        boolean flag = true;
        while (flag){
            try {
                String message = bfr.readLine();
                System.out.println("["+bfr.toString()+"]: "+bfr.toString());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                flag = false;
                interrupt();
            }
        } //while loop brackets
    } // run brackets
//-----------and here---------------//
    public void communication(BufferedReader bfr, String userID, ServerMessaging serverMessaging) throws IOException { //sending messages
       try {
           System.out.println("> Communication has starter");

        boolean flag = true;
        while(flag){
            String message = bfr.readLine();

            StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter(); /** Errors might be here**/
            stringwriter.write(message);
            serverMessaging.sendMessage(stringwriter.toString()); // to send messages throught serverMessaging
        }} catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sb6X.png
````

Comment: Why don't you print 'message' and instead printing 'bfr.toString'?

Comment: @Nkoyee okay that works, but how can I print out the peers user name with the message that is being sent (userID that the person added at the start)

Comment: As far as I can see from your given code snippet. Are you talking about the 'userId' parameter passed in the 'communication()' method? Do you want to print it just for debugging? Then simply keep a String variable reference in the class level. And print it along the message.